# Bokeh Server hangs on Startup (Windows, Python 3.8)

Tags: python, bokeh, python-3.8

When I run the Bokeh server, it hangs-up on startup with only the following log messages:

```
Starting Bokeh server version 1.4.0 (running on Tornado 6.0.3)
User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
```

There is no output generated.

Versions info:

- Windows 10
- Bokeh 1.4.0
- Python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bokeh server 1.4 does not function with Python 3.8 on Windows due to a change on the Python side that is incompatible with Tornado.  The upcoming Bokeh 2.0 release has an update to add compatibility with 3.8. You can see details here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9507

You will need to either:

- Use a different version of python, or
- Wait for Bokeh 2.0 to be released, or
- Apply the change described in the issue manually